# FVM Error!!! HEAD is now at 84a1e904f4 [flutter_releases] Could not install 3.10.0

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, fvm

I have to modify a project that makes use of flutter version manager.
I had to opt in for FVM. did the set up correctly. but i can't make use of it to run the application
thne i am getting this error if i run with a version i download or while trying to run the app[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtFuP.png)

I checked the versions i have, and tryin to use any i get this error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brg8f.png)

Comment: run fvm install 3.10.0 --verbose to see further info